# Number of positive integers less than or equal to $1000$ and are not divisible by $17,19,23$. Four Options are there .... $854, 153, 160$ and none

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

My answer was $153$, it's long process to get that, notice that $17,19,23$ are primes so is there any particular way to handle these types of problems? Please help me.

Comment: Yes, there is a particular way to handle this kind of problems: it is called the inclusion-exclusion principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). It is what user236182 has used in its answer, combined with a De Morgan law. In its answer it is important that all numbers are relatively prime, otherwise we will need to use lcms instead of products (but in this case lcm(17,19)=17*19, etc.)

Comment: @JoseBrox Thanks, I've added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=\{k\mid k\in\mathbb Z^+, k\le 1000,17\mid k\}\\B=\{k\mid k\in\mathbb Z^+, k\le 1000,19\mid k\}\\C=\{k\mid k\in\mathbb Z^+, k\le 1000,23\mid k\}$$

$$\left|\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}\right|=1000-\left|A\cup B\cup C\right|$$

$$=1000-(|A|+|B|+|C|)$$

$$+(|A\cap B|+|B\cap C|+|C\cap A|)-|A\cap B\cap C|$$

$$|A|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{17}\rfloor,\, |B|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{19}\rfloor,\, |C|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{23}\rfloor$$

$$|A\cap B|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{17\cdot 19}\rfloor,\, |B\cap C|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{19\cdot 23}\rfloor,$$

$$|C\cap A|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{23\cdot 17}\rfloor,\, |A\cap B\cap C|=\lfloor\frac{1000}{17\cdot 19\cdot 23}\rfloor$$

Edit: I used a [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_complements), [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and the fact that $17,19,23$ are pairwise coprime, i.e. $\gcd(17,19)=\gcd(19,23)=\gcd(23,17)=1$.

Answer (score 3):

There are $\lfloor \frac {1000}{17} \rfloor = 58$ that are divisible by $17$  You can compute the other two and subtract each from $1000$, but you have subtracted the multiples of $17 \cdot 19$ (and the other two pairs) twice, so add back in $\lfloor \frac {1000}{17\cdot 19} \rfloor = 3$ and the other two.  As $17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 \gt 1000$ you don't need to worry about multiples of all three.  It will be close to $854$